# Small sample size with very skewed right response

Tags: regression, random-forest, skewness, small-sample, boosting

I have a dataset of 300 observations with 7 predictor variables with 1 continuous response variable.  The response is strongly skewed to the right and there are no significant correlations among any of the predictors or the response.  I have attempted several different models including XGBoost, random forests, etc. Even transforming of the response hasn't helped.  Any advice on how one should approach a problem like this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems 7 predictors have no relation with response variable. Given there really is no relation, the statistical methods can not create the relation.

Comment: What is the response measuring? Is it a count, an amount of money, the size of something, a concentration, an angle, ...?

Comment: Sorry didn't clarify that.  The response is proportions between 0 and 1 with most values falling close to 0 and the max being around .14.